# Speed difference HFS and NTFS for data

Tags: mac, ntfs, storage, hfs, hfs+

I have two partitions, one NTFS and the other a Mac OS X HFS+ Journaled drive. My data mainly consists of Music (mp3, m4a files, videos (mkv, avi, wmv) and stored files (iso, exe and development files)

My main thought in my head would be that the HFS+ partition would be better for storage, but then again I won't be able to see the files in Windows.

I know there is MacDrive by mediafour, but it seems that it won't be native file management and may cause a performance loss on the Windows Side.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the second to last line unless you want the question to get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not really matter. See [here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=990821) for more on the subject (though not a lot more).

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a direct comparison, it may be relevant.  I happen to be doing some large scale writing of data to portable hard drives for delivery to a customer.  The file system requirement on the portable hard drives recently changed from nonjournaled HFS+ to NTFS.

The job that writes the data to the hard drive takes 50% longer on NTFS than on nonjournaled HFS+.  Moreover, that job also has to receive the data over a LAN, and the LAN speed doesn't change, so the actual disk write to NTFS may actually be about twice as long.  Both drives are mounted on identical machines running Redhat Enterprise Linux, using the relevant elrepo drivers.

I don't know how much of this advantage for HFS+ is journaling, which would then go away if I were comparing journaled HFS+ drives to NTFS drives, and how much is basic differences in the file system.